# sqoop import to hive table error

Tags: hive, sqoop

Hello i try to insert as400 table to hive table, so i create a hive table with the same schema of the as400 table but i add a columns processedate (timestamp)
this is my hive table:

```
CREATE external TABLE IF NOT EXISTS default.AS400TEST (
One INT,
Two STRING,
..
N   INT             
)
PARTITIONED BY (processedate TIMESTAMP)
STORED AS  TEXTFILE 
location  '/tmp/AS400TEST;
```

I run this sqoop command:

```
sqoop import --verbose --driver $DRIVER_CLASS --connect $URL --username $LOGIN --password $PASSWORD \
--table $TABLE \
--target-dir $DIR \
-m 1 --hive-import --hive-table default.AS400TEST \
--hive-partition-key "processedate"
```

My problem is that the map remains on 0% for more than 30 min and i kill the job. 
did i need to change Something?

Another question: how to insert the column timestamp with sqoop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table probably is large and one mapper (`-m 1`) can not complete the task within a reasonable time. Try to increase this parameter (see details in [documentation](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.7/SqoopUserGuide.html#_controlling_parallelism)).

To insert timestamp column use `--map-column-hive 'timestamp_column_name=TIMESTAMP'`.

Comment: `ERROR tool.ImportTool: Import failed: No primary key could be found for table . Please specify one with --split-by or perform a sequential import with '-m 1'` i got this error when i add -m4

Comment: Yes, as mentioned in docs if there is no primary key, you need to explicitly specify column in the `--split-by` parameter that are needed for breaking the data into multiple independent tasks. The best choice is non-string column which values are uniformly distributed across its range. Try to add, e.g. `-m 8 --split-by One`

Comment: `-m 4` is default value

Comment: thank you @IskuskovAlexander ; i use --hive-partition-key "to_porcess_ts" (it's a timestamp datatype) and i add PARTITIONED BY (to_porcess_ts TIMESTAMP) to hive but i got this error  `Cannot add partition column to_porcess_ts of type string as it cannot be converted to type timestamp`

Comment: @ZiedHermi I think you actually want to partitioned by `DATE` (`DATE` values describe a particular year/month/day, e.g. `2018-05-01`).

Comment: @ZiedHermi Is my advice about increasing mappers number helpful for you?

Comment: yes it helps, but how to know the maw number of mappers that i can use, it's a yarn configuration?

Comment: You need to find out the optimal number of mappers (not max) - it depends on your data. See https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HowManyMapsAndReduces

Comment: i got this error after runing my sqoop command  `ERROR tool.ImportTool: Import failed: java.io.IOException: 0.00099183269793457189831998626608480979817417111377153560169972479343414306640625 is greater than 0.0008087290918297212376964075840227001712445797920736367814242839813232421875`

Comment: Which column type is used for splitting?

Comment: i have to change the column used for --split-by? all my tables have the varchar datatype